# How to add a timestamp to nodemon?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am seeing all the requests being made, but I would like to add a timestamp to see when did each one happen. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use morgan https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

Comment: any way to achieve with nodemon?

Answer (score 3):

Use a nodemon config file named *nodemon.json* to print timestamp:

```
{
  "events": {
    "start": "date"
  }
}
```

And specify the config file when running nodemon `nodemon --config nodemon.json server.js`.